# How To Display Featured Products In Product Page

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to display the featured products in the product page at the bottom

[image]

Comment: i have tried from the catalog section also tried to write the code in the feature product  in the cms static block but how to paste the code in porto theme in the product page

Comment: What featured products do you refer to? How are you setting products to be featured? Or do you mean 'Related Products' or 'Product Upsells' in fact? See [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/related-products-up-sells-cross-sells-in-magento/) for reference...

Comment: yes i mean related products

Comment: See [here](http://themeforest.net/item/porto-ultimate-responsive-magento-theme/9725864/comments?page=7) and [here](http://themeforest.net/item/porto-ultimate-responsive-magento-theme/9725864/comments?page=143). Voting to close as theme specific. Use the support channel and comments directly with theme developers as per the above links for support with the 'Porto' theme.

Comment: @zigojacko i donot have any problem with the voting i have tried with this if there is a solution then please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to determine what the block name is for this so-called featured products block. The operating assumption here is that the block is properly declared in XML somewhere as "favorites" (i.e. `<block name="favorites" />`).

Once you know the block's name in layout, it can be inserted below the product view area via layout XML. You can use the following:

```
<catalong_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <action method="insert" after="-">
            <block>favorites</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalong_product_view>
```